# Flash game engine

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need simple game engine with pixel-perfect collision detection, camera component with following function, network and particle components would be desirable. Anyone knows whether the engine right under these requirements?

Answer (score 9):

Definitely look into [flixel](http://flixel.org/). It already covers a lot of your requirements.

Also check out [Flash Game Dojo](http://www.flashgamedojo.com/go/). That will help getting you started.

**Update:** For the sake of completeness: Also look at [FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.net/). It is similar to flixel but has some other strenghts/philosophy. Check out the Flash Game Dojo page for a brief comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add [Pushbutton Engine](http://pushbuttonengine.com/) as another candidate. This is a modular engine so you don't need to include the whole feature set if you don't need it.

Comment: it's have only 5 tutorials :( very hard for understanding

Comment: 5 tutorials isn't too bad to get started. I'm sure the community over there would help if you're stuck (they have a community-forum just like flixel and FlashPunk)